# Crystal Report not Opening except on Development Server

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

My crystal report is not opening on a web form but it is fine on a development server when I publish it on the server. It is giving the following error.

> The system cannot find the file specified. 
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException:
>   The system cannot find the file
>   specified.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated
>   during the execution of the current
>   web request. Information regarding the
>   origin and location of the exception
>   can be identified using the exception
>   stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [COMException (0x80004005): The system
>   cannot find the file specified. ]
>   CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc.ReportClientDocumentClass.Open(Object&
>   DocumentPath, Int32 Options) +0 [snip]
>
> ---
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.4952; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.4955

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the report document.  `ReportClientDocumentClass.Open(Object& DocumentPath, Int32 Options)` is where its failing; `Object& DocumentPath` is what cannot be found.

Whatever report file you created and have on your development machine, you have to put it on the server in a place where the account running the website (Network Service?) can access it, such as in the /bin folder or some other folder of the website.

If you are not sure what file you are missing, grab [Process monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645), put it on the server, and recreate the error.  It'll show the file that isn't being found and where the website is looking for it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that folder have specific rights where the reports are placed